# Confusion in understanding of 2D, 3D Convolutions in Convolutional Neural Networks 3D or multi-spectral images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Anyone please explain the difference between 2D and 3D convolutions in CNN (Deep Learning) using 3D or multi-spectral images?

Comment: The Image is 3D stack of 2D Images or does the image have multiple input channels like (R,G,B) or is a mixture of all?

Answer (score -1):

all convolution operation has padding for maintaining output size [w, h]

- 2D Convolution

  input size = [w, h]

  conv filter = [n, n]

  output size = [w, h]
- 3D convolution

  input size = [w, h, c]

  conv filter = [n, n, d]

  output size = [w, h, c']
- 2D convolution for 3D input (usually used this form)

  input size = [w, h, c]

  conv filter = [n, n, c]

  output size = [w, h]

  if you want to get output size with [w, h, c'], you need c' times operation.